# Facebook Actionscript API - Can't get extended permissions to work

Tags: facebook, actionscript, authentication, permissions

I'm working with the Facebook Actionscript API (no PHP or Javascript), and I'm having trouble granting access to extended permissions, like publish_actions.

I'm using the following login:

```
var opts:Object = {perms:'read_stream,publish_actions,offline_access,user_photos'};
Facebook.login(handleLogin, opts);
```

I get two "Request for Permission" windows.  The first says my app needs access to "Your Photos".  The second says my app would like permission to "Access posts in your News Feed" and "Access your data anytime".  Why can't I request access to "publish_actions"?

It looks like there may be two permissions levels - regular and "extended".
It looks like extended permissions may require a "scope" parameter, instead of "perms".

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how/where to use the "scope" parameter.  Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "scope" for the key instead of "perms" like this:

```
var opts:Object = {scope:"read_stream,publish_actions,offline_access,user_photos"};
Facebook.login(onLogin, opts);
```